# How can I make 5 or more products columns in woocommerce shop page

Tags: woocommerce

I made a woocommerce custom theme from psd. I need to show auto colums or 5 or more colums. I search a lot but found 4 max colums. So, Anyone please tell me, How can I make auto colums or 5 more colums in woocommerce shop or archive page?

Regards
Tariq

Answer (score 0):

You can change the number of columns via the `loop_shop_columns` filter.

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_columns', 'so_30113923_shop_columns' );
function so_30113923_shop_columns(){
  return 5;
}
```

Keep in mind that this only changes the HTML classes and specifically where the `first` and `last` classes are printed (`last` is on every 5th element now instead of 4th). WooCommerce's CSS styles still have widths for 4 columns, so you will need to write custom CSS rules for your new columns.